# requests not going through in nodejs and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, controller, router

I have this code where I am trying to receive data from the user and it should be inserted into the db directly without any module just a controller, can someone tell me how can I do that, I know we can get the user data in the req.body, but I don't know how to send it back to the controller here is the
P.S  user will be sending around 10 or  more fields that will be inserted

here is the code
**controller**

```
 sql.query(`INSERT INTO Admin (LoginID,Password,Preference,Name,Last Name) values ? ` ,  (err, result)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Something bad happened: ' + err);

            return res.status(500);
        }

        console.log('Response from controller', result);
        res.json(result);
    });
}
module.exports = {test}
```

**and this is the router page
Router**

```
router.post('/CreateOrganizer',(req,res)=>{
    
    organizer.test
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should proceed:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});


app.post('',(req, res, next) => {
  
const user = req.body;
   // use the same key in the query that you are getting from body.
  const sql = "INSERT INTO Admin (LoginID,Password,Preference,Name,Last Name) 
  VALUES ('user.LoginID', 'user.Password', 'user.Preference', 'user.Name''user.LastName')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
       console.error('Something bad happened: ' + err);
       return res.status(500);
    }
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });

})
```

There are several tutorials available online that can help you to achieve the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821318/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-table-using-node-and-express).