# How do I send to node.js database after clicking on html canvas element?

Tags: node.js, canvas, ejs

I have an .ejs file and I added a canvas. How do I do send values to nodejs when I click on the html canvas element named circle? Is there supposed to be a POST method used with fetch?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

          

<canvas id ="canvas" style="border: solid 5px blue";></canvas>

<script>

    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 800;

var circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(250, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
circle.closePath
ctx.fill(circle);

canvas.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

var circle_1 = ctx.isPointInPath(circle, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)

if (circle_1) {
//I want to send values from here
}

})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the insert to database with nodejs solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to exchange data from html to backend is using on of these 02 methods

- [Html Form action](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)
- [Ajax](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/ajax/)

Since your event is not raised from a **common form**, you need ajax. So in your "onclick" event put something like this:

**Without external library**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var theUrl = "/some/express/router";
xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"}));

//source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519299/3957754
```

You have another options to use ajax:

- Fetch: [Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)
- Axios: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-axios-in-vanilla-javascript-2dbf176e08d4

### Backend

In the previous example,  **/some/express/router** refers to some route in your backend.

Before of use ajax, you need to develop a backend http endpoint to receive data and  store it in your favorite database. Check :

- [How to insert data into MySQL table using Node and express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821318/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-table-using-node-and-express)
- https://www.tutsmake.com/first-crud-node-express-js-mysql-example/